# Docking form horizontally without showing form

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

What I want is docking forms multiple times horizontally. But I had a simple problem with it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Panel1: TPanel;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
  tmpform: TfColorForm;
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lForm: TColorForm;
begin
  lForm := TColorForm.Create(Application);
  tmpform := lForm;
  lform.Show;
  lForm.ManualDock(Panel1, tmpform, alTop);
end;
```

And my form what i want to dock multiple times...

```
type
TColorForm = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
  ColorForm: TColorForm;

  implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfColorForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action:   TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TfColorForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Color := Random($FFFFFF);
  Caption := IntToHex(Color, 6);
end;
```

The Result is ok, but how can I solve it without showing the form before I dock it.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you move "lform.Show;" after "lForm.ManualDock(.." ?

Comment: All forms will be vertical, not horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the `TColorForm` from flashing before it gets docked, by setting its `BorderStyle` to `bsNone`.

Or, if you want to hide the forms until all of them have been created, simply hide (`Visible := False`) the panel, and show it after you have created all forms.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the form flashed before it's docked. Thank you for your help!